# looping over subdirectories and files in the sub directories in linux

Tags: linux, shell, loops, command, line

I am new to the site and to Linux.
I am trying to write a command line code in Linux to loop over sub directories of a given directory  then over the files in these sub-directories. perform a certain function then output the result to new sub-directories with the same name in a different directory.
Here is my code

```
for dirname in $(ls);
do 
    cd $dirname
        for file in $(ls)
        do
    mkdir -p ~/path/to/new directory/$dirname/$filname
    zcat $file| ~/path/to/ptogram  stdin --outdir ~/path/to/new directory/$dirname/$file
    done
    cd ..
done
```

although the code is working , i want to know if there is a simpler way.. I have a feeling my code is not clean maybe because I am not familiar with all the syntax in Linux
Thank you!

Comment: This might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - make sure to read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask before posting, though.

Comment: Or, ServerFault, or Unix and Linux...